# Syncfusion gridDataControl pagination - version 9.0.1.20

Tags: syncfusion

I'm using an older version of syncfusion, version 9.0.1.20. I was wondering if this version provides pagination support for the gridDataControl? or was it only added into a version after 10? Also, I was wondering if there's any work-around to achieve pagination(OnDemandPaging) in the gridDataControl with the version of syncfusion I'm using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Paging support is added only in 9.3.0.61 version however if you want to display the data without sorting and filtering, then you can try the below workaround,

“Create GridDataControl and change the ItemSource of GridDataControl based on page navigation. So that you can load the ItemSource in OnDemand”